# How to write if condition in <script type=“text/x-magento-templ”>?

Tags: magento2

How to write if condition in below script

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <div class="wrapper">
if(data.id == 10) {
        <input id="<%- data.id %>" name="<%- data.name %>" placeholder="<%- data.placeholder %>" />
}
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <% if (data.id == 10) { %>
        <input id="<%- data.id %>" name="<%- data.name %>" placeholder="<%- data.placeholder %>" />
    <% } %>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I want to make the dropdown value selected using the ternary operator, is there have any way to achieve that

Comment: Hello @senthil have you tried dropdown

Comment: Sir, please look at my question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323853/how-to-pass-data-as-parameter-with-block-function-in-script-type-text-x-magent